# while-loop to number 6174

Tags: python-3.x

I'am beginner in programming and have struggled for a while with one task.
Want to write a program wich finds out how many iterations is needed to arrive at the number 6174 from the specified number.

For example.: if I take number 2341 and sort it.

1) 4321-1234=3087
 2) 8730-378=8352
 3) 8532-2358=6174 (in this case it`s needed 3 iterations.)

And I have to use ,,while loop,, that it runs a code until it comes to number 6174 and stops.

I wrote a code:

```
n =input('write for nummbers ')
n=str(n)
i=0  
i+=1     #"i" show how many times iteration happend.
large = "".join(sorted(n, reverse=True))
little = "".join(sorted(n,))
n = int(large) - int(little)
print(n, i)
```

Can you give mee some hint how I could run it with while loop.

Comment: @Marc Any reason you used `<>` instead of `!=`?

Comment: pseudo-code, to give OP something to think about ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# untested, all bugs are free  ;)
n = input('write for nummbers ')
n = int(n) # you need n as a number
i=0  
while n != 6174:
    i += 1     #"i" show how many times iteration happened.
    large = "".join(sorted(str(n), reverse=True))
    little = "".join(sorted(str(n),))
    n = int(large) - int(little)
print(n, i)
```